# Returning undefined value from C++ method

Tags: c++, templates, undefined

I have a class that is of the form

```
template <typename T>
class c {

    bool hasChild = *something*;
    T *child;

public:

    T getChild() {
        if(hasChild) {
           return *child;
        } else {
           return 0; // <<-- this line
        }

}
```

My actual class is very different, but this represents the specific problem I'm having more simply. When hasChild is false, getChild is to return an undefined value. However since c++ has no NULL value like Java and other languages, I am not sure what I can return since I have no other reference to an object of type T and am unable to construct one since it is a template. As required by the API, the method `method` must return an object of type T, so changing the method signature to return a T* as suggested on other stack overflow posts is not an option.

Thanks!

Comment: Look up `std::optional` (or `std::experimental::optional`), which look to fit your purpose. If instead you intend to return a `T*` to a child, then you could simply return `nullptr`

Comment: It really depends on the context.  If `child` should be a nullable value, then you could use `std::optional`.  If however `hasChild = false`  indicates that an invariant of class `c` was violated then you should just throw an exception.

Comment: Wouldn't using 'std::optional' require that the method signature be changed?

Comment: You could also consider exposing `hasChild` through some other function, similar to `vector::empty`.

Comment: The simple answer is: `return T()`, does this meet your need?

Comment: A little off topic, but simply returning a newly constructed `T` would be misleading, because calling `getChild` twice would give two different objects. If anything, constructing a new child returning it might be better.

Comment: @elinx You're a magician. Thanks!!!

Comment: @Tas The value returned by getChild when hasChild is false is undefined behavior, so it doesn't matter in this case. I just need filler so it'll compile. Thanks.

Comment: @Tas Calling `getChild` twice will always give two different objects, so I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Note that `return T()` will cause issues if `T` is not default constructible.  I agree that the correct solution is to `throw` something.

Comment: Ah, you're right... I didn't test for that. So this doesn't work.

Comment: @drew.neely As I said, it's a simple answer, it really depends on what your `T` is, better if it's a class. Or else you should use some template tricks to check whether your `T` is default-constructible which is way too complicated I thought.

Comment: I just realized that there is an out of box tool right there in c++11 to verify whether a type is default-constructible, see [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_default_constructible)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically, you would solve this with the use of [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) (`std::experimental::optional` if not C++17), to indicate that a `c` may or may not have a child. Note that if you were returning a `T*` simply returning `nullptr` would work. Both would require a change to the function signature, which you've said isn't allowed.

This really only leaves you with two options:

1. `throw` an `exception` if a child isn't found
2. Return a newly constructed `T`, [as @elinx highlights in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49041761/returning-undefined-value-from-c-method#comment85088923_49041761)

Since [you've stated that it's undefined to not have a child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49041761/returning-undefined-value-from-c-method#comment85089106_49041761) you should probably throw an exception. The onus would be on callers to ensure the object has a child before calling `getChild`. If you simply return a `T()`, the caller may not realise there was no child.

Answer (score 0):

Remember there is the **null-object concept** - which returns an instance that fits the defined interface and always returns a valid object.
It can be tested for object.isNull() or just does nothing (better).

This is common when a reference has to be returned.(According to uncle bob: don't return null and don't return anything that has to be checked for further usage. Exceptions are also a kind of return that haveto be checked.)